# Dojo events: getting it to work with dynamically added DOM elements

Tags: dom, events, dojo, dom-events

I have a method of a class as follows:

```
add_file: function(name, id, is_new){
    // HTML: <div class="icon mime zip">name.zip <a>x</a></div>
    var components = name.split('.');
    var extension = components[components.length-1];
    this.container.innerHTML += "<div id='"+id+"' class='icon mime "+extension+"'>"+name+" <a id='remove-"+id+"' href='#remove'>x</a></div>";
    // Add event to a tag
        dojo.connect(dojo.byId('remove-'+id), 'onclick', function(ev){
            // here i am
        });
},
```

All is working well, until I run this method more than once. The first time the event is registered correctly, and clicking the 'x' will run the "here i am" function. However, once I add more than one node (and yes, the ID is different), the event is registered to the last node, but removed from any previous ones.

In affect I have this:

```
<div id="field[photos]-filelist">
<div id="file1" class="icon mime jpg">file1.jpg <a id="remove-file1" href="#remove">x</a></div>
<div id="file2" class="icon mime jpg">file2.jpg <a id="remove-file2" href="#remove">x</a></div>
</div>
```

...and the remove link only works for the last node (remove-file2 in this case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are using the innerHTML +=

That is going to take the existing html, convert it to plain markup, and then completely create new nodes from the markup. In the process, all of the nodes with events get replaced with nodes that look exactly the same but are not connected to anything.

The correct way to do this is to use dojo.place(newNodeOrHTML, refNode, positionString)

```
var myNewHTML = "<div id='"+id+"' class='icon mime "+extension+"'>"+name+" <a id='remove-"+id+"' href='#remove'>x</a></div>"

//This won't work as is breaks all the connections between nodes and events
this.container.innerHTML += myNewHTML;


//This will work because it uses proper dom manipulation techniques
dojo.place(myNewHTML, this.container, 'last');
```

Comment: Minus the minor typo (missing , after this.container) the solution was perfect! Thanks!

Comment: Nice! I added in the comma - Cheers